# Im trying to execute python --version command from Jenkins job, and jenkins job tells me it cant recognize the command

Tags: python, jenkins

## Setup:

- Windows 10
- Installed pip3 and python3 (can be executed everywhere)
- Installed Jenkins
- Installed PowerShell plugin
- Created a job

I want to run job on Jenkins master at my own computer.

When I try to run `python --version` it gives me this error (same as with robot tests): 
(freestyle project and powershell chosen)

```
>Started by user admin
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\python test - freestyle
[python test - freestyle] $ powershell.exe -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\Windows\TEMP\jenkins4675506517232608628.ps1
**Program 'python.exe' failed to run: The file cannot be accessed by the systemAt**
C:\Windows\TEMP\jenkins4675506517232608628.ps1:2 char:1
+ python --version
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.
At C:\Windows\TEMP\jenkins4675506517232608628.ps1:2 char:1
+ python --version
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed

>Build step 'PowerShell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

It seems it can't find the program.

[image]

Comment: Have you set python path in Manage Jenkins >> Global Tool Configuration ??

Comment: I see that in your setup you're installing python3. Try `python3 --version` or `python3 -V`